# 301 redirect latency

Tags: dns, 301-redirect, latency

I want my website to work either way for both `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com`, so I setup an `A record` for the root domain `mysite.com` and then created a `CNAME` record which points `www.mysite.com` to the host record `mysite.com`.

Now if I type `www.mysite.com`, it's actually resulting in a 301 redirect to `mysite.com`. But every time the redirection is causing about 3 seconds latency (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot of 301 redirect latency]

Have I made any mistake in configuring my domain?

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing that also in my site, and that time is not the redirect time - a redirection (as it is called) takes *almost* no time.

That line represents the time between the HTTP call and the server response, which involves the DNS resolution process, the server handling the call, and receiving the HTTP response.

You can see it in more detail in this picture:

[image]

(*Waiting* refers to all the time the server spends performing operations until it responds)

Most browsers also [cache 301 calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s), which makes this process almost immediate.

Comment: Thanks mate, but the confusion is, if I use `mysite.com` directly, it only takes 685ms wait time, with `www.mysite.com` redirection 1.07s wait time!! I manage DNS with CloudFlare, is it due to the CDN or my web host server is not optimized.

3s to render a page is huge in case of UX, in compare to 700ms if visitor use root domain `mysite.com`

Comment: For what you're telling me, if you have configured a CNAME redirect in CloudFare, contact them because it'll have to do with them